# Is the tutorial mission broken?

Tags: fate-of-the-world

The tutorial mission starts you with $280 and instructs you to get 4 agents for $200. The whole point of getting an agent is being able to play a card in a region.

$80, however, are only enough for *three* of the cheapest cards (the offices, coming at $25 each). So getting a fourth agent is a waste of $50 in the first place...

Or is it? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

A reason they mightve given you a few bucks short might be so that you have to pay attention to what region actually can make good use of a policital office.. both needs welfare offices but only one is unstable from what I can tell. Could be a lame way of giving you some actual decisions to make in that lame tutorial campaign :)

Answer (score 1):

Those $50 for the fourth agent are not wasted, because the **money does not carry over between turns**.

It is intended to use only three cards, but you can buy an extra agent already, saving you $50 on the next turn. This is also done to ensure that people don't make the "mistake" that comes with buying only 3 agents and putting them in the wrong spot.